# blender cycle glass issue(2.8); It looks thicker than the actual thickness of an object

Tags: glass

[image]like the title
the render result looks quite odd. 
Although I tried to make this wine glass mesh thinner, it still does not affect the result. 
so, if there is another point I do not know,please let me know 
thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Check your normals

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos can you please formulate this as a proper answer?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos  oh.. I flipped the normal and the problem solved.. thank you.. ^^;;;;;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reduce the roughness on the glass material

Comment: Thank you.. ^^;